# Block all objects' public access in S3 by CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have over 100 files in S3 where some of the files have public access.  Is there a cli to set all objects (not bucket) permission to block public access inside one bucket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To block all the public access to you S3 bucket you can use the `put-public-access-block` command. Here is the command:

```
aws s3api put-public-access-block \
    --bucket my-bucket \
    --public-access-block-configuration "BlockPublicAcls=true,IgnorePublicAcls=true,BlockPublicPolicy=true,RestrictPublicBuckets=true"
```

To verify the current access status of your bucket you can use the `get-public-access-block` command. Here is the command to get the public access configuration of you bucket:

```
aws s3api get-public-access-block \
    --bucket my-bucket
```

For more details you can follow [AWS CLI command - put-public-access-block](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-public-access-block.html)

Comment: @hatted You are most Welcome! If it is working you can count it as accepted answer if you think so. Thank you too.

Comment: I marked accepted answer because I can just change the bucket name to change those buckets by cli, which is the fastest way to do it.
BTW, do you know the cli to change just one object public permission?

Comment: Hope this link will help for single object permission change. You need to set bucket policy for single object change. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

Answer (score 4):

You can use **S3 Block Public Access** to override object-level settings and keep the bucket private:

- Go to the **Permissions** tab for the bucket
- Click **Block public access**
- Activate *"Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)"*

In general, all these Block Public Access settings should be activated unless there is a specific reason to turn them off.

This can also be done via the AWS CLI. See: [put-public-access-block — AWS Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-public-access-block.html) (`IgnorePublicAcls`)

Comment: For some reason, this command was depreciated/removed in `awscli` v2

Comment: It's still there. Make sure you use `s3api` rather than `s3` as in: `aws s3api put-public-access-block --bucket ...`

Comment: It appears that it is now per bucket rather than global account as in v1.

Comment: I think that this API call has always been at the bucket-level. There is a `PublicAccessBlock` at the Account level, but I can't find an API call to edit that (but it can be edited in the S3 management console). The documentation also says: "When Amazon S3 evaluates the PublicAccessBlock configuration for a bucket or an object, it checks the `PublicAccessBlock` configuration for both the bucket and the bucket owner's account. If the `PublicAccessBlock` configurations are different, Amazon S3 uses the most restrictive combination of the bucket-level and account-level settings."

Comment: Thanks for the reply; you are correct. I previously called this at the account level as part of a script - perhaps it never worked.